# Angular form invalid when checkbox unchecked then checked

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, angular-material

I have a form that has three checkboxes, which are checked by default. If a uncheck the checkbox, and enter a value in the form below it and then submit, everything works fine.

If I uncheck one of the checkboxes then check it again and click submit, it says that the form is invalid.

https://angular-khmzeq.stackblitz.io

```
<form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off">
    <h2>Terms</h2>
    <div *ngIf="!this.input.data.acceptDate" [class.entry]="!form.get('acceptDate').value">
        <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="acceptDate"><strong>I accept the date</strong>
        </mat-checkbox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="!form.get('acceptDate').value">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="optDate" placeholder="Preferred date" formControlName="optDate" [min]="now" required />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="optDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #optDate></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!this.input.data.acceptPod" [class.entry]="!form.get('acceptPod').value">
        <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="acceptPod"><strong>I accept the point of delivery</strong> 
        </mat-checkbox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="!form.get('acceptPod').value">
            <input matInput formControlName="optPod" type="text" placeholder="Preferred point of delivery" required />
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div [class.entry]="!form.get('acceptPrice').value">
        <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="acceptPrice"><strong>I accept the price</strong> 
        </mat-checkbox>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="!form.get('acceptPrice').value">
            <input matInput formControlName="price" type="number" placeholder="Price per {{ fuelQuery?.fuel.standardUnit }}" required />
            <span matSuffix>{{ fuelQuery?.payment.currency }}</span>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

</form>
```

```
async submitCounter({ valid, value }) {
      if(valid) {
// submit form
    }

    if(!valid){
      console.log('not valid');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time your form is valid because the following field does not exist as **I accept the date** is checked:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="!form.get('acceptDate').value">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="optDate" placeholder="Preferred date" formControlName="optDate" [min]="now" required />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="optDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #optDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But when you unchecked the **I accept the date** and check again the form is invalid because with uncheck the form holds the above field which contains `required` and the form is invalid if `optDate` does not have value. This applies to your other fields as well.

It seems weird to me why this is happening but for now use a method to check the form validity.

```
isValidForm() {
  if (!this.form.get('acceptPrice').value && !this.form.get('price').value) {
    return false;
  } else return true;
}
```

The above is just an example. Put your all conditions. My knowledge is limited on why this is happening.

Comment: Right, thanks alot for the explanation! What would you recommend to fix this? optDate needs to be required if acceptDate is unchecked

Comment: @houssam98 provided a quick fix for now. Maybe it's a bug or my knowledge is limited.